# Dart map value says null after writing key value pairs to it

Tags: flutter, dart

I got a map declared

```
Map<String, String>? testMap;
```

I am trying to write to this map inside of a for loop -

```
result.forEach((item) {
   if (item.contains(contact)) {
       testMap?["display_name"] =
          test[i].displayName;
       testMap?["phone_number"] =
          test[i].phones[x].number;
   }
});
```

After all this when I print(testMap), I get null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your map:

```
Map<String, String>? testMap = {};
```